# dynamically adding div elements using for loop

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using a for loop to dynamically add `div` elements to a parent node in JavaScript, but I am unable to do because it adds only one element.

My code is this:

```
var row = document.getElementById("rowel");

var col = document.createElement('div');
col.className = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mr-auto";



var card = document.createElement('img');
card.src = "./assets/building.jpg";
card.style["max-width"] = "350px";
card.alt = "cant displayed";

col.appendChild(card);

for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {

    row.appendChild(col);

}
```

Can some please help me to solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to add 5 exact same 'col' to 'row'?

Comment: There's only one `col` object. If you want to create more than one, move the `document.createElement` code into the loop.

Comment: example of expected output? like <div></div>

Comment: You create one element and you keep trying to append it. Since it is the same object, it just removes itself and adds it to the new location. Clone it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### When you are doing the following:

```
for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
     row.appendChild(col);
}
```

you are adding **5 exact same** `col` object.

It's like saying,

*"Hey, kid **A** is my Child." 5 times.*

**In your case, it already knows that COL is a child of ROW. Its pointless to tell it million different times**
.

### What you want is:

*"Hey, kid **A** is my Child."

*"Hey, kid **B** who looks exactly like **A** is my Child."

...

*"Hey, kid **E** who looks exactly like **A** is my Child."

Hence, this is what your code should look like:

```
for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
   var col = document.createElement('div');
   col.className = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mr-auto";

   var card = document.createElement('img');
   card.src = "./assets/building.jpg";
   card.style["max-width"] = "350px";
   card.alt = "cant displayed";

   col.appendChild(card);
   row.appendChild(col);

}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you so much ...got it

Answer (score 2):

You are adding the same element in each iteration. Create a new object in every iteration and it should work

```
var row = document.getElementById("rowel");

for (let index = 0; index < 5; index++) {
    var col = document.createElement('div');
    col.className = "col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 mr-auto";

    var card = document.createElement('img');
    card.src = "./assets/building.jpg";
    card.style["max-width"] = "350px";
    card.alt = "cant displayed";

    col.appendChild(card);

    row.appendChild(col);

}
```

Comment: yes i want to add the same element, because in some situation i need the same image to display .if i will not create a new object then it wont add ??